# Remove automatic comment leader

Tags: comments

When I press return at the end of a comment line, vim will automatically insert the comment leader on the next line as well:

```
// My comment bla bla
// ‸
```

I like this feature and I would like to leave it switched on. However, quite often, I also want to write uncommented code on the next line. Is there an easy way to configure vim in such a way that pressing backspace once in this position will remove the whole comment leader? I find it at little bit annoying to always have to press backspace three times.

Comment: Press `Ctrl-U` to clear the whole line?

Comment: Thanks, I didn’t know about that one. This might definitively be an option as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a simple mapping;

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <bs> getline('.') =~# '^//\s*$' ? "<c-u>" : "<bs>"
```

Note that if your `backspace` setting includes `start`, this will delete the comment regardless of whether it was automatically entered or not.

Alternatively, here is a slightly different workflow.  I use the following snippet; pressing `<cr>` will insert the comment leader, pressing `shift`+`<cr>` will not.  Note that not all terminals support this key combination.

```
execute "set <f26>=\<esc>OM"

inoremap <silent><expr> <f26>
    \ synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.')-1, 1), 'name') =~? 'comment'
    \ ? "<cr><c-u>"
    \ : "<cr>"
```

Comment: Unfortunately both variants don’t work for me. I run vim in tmux and it looks like shift + <cr> won’t work with tmux. But I’m also unsure whether it would fit my workflow: I’m looking for something that works after pressing ‘o’ as well.

The first one looks like what I want, but vim will just remove the space characters.

Comment: Okay I just tried it with a blank .vimrc and it works. So something else seems to be interfering with this :/

Comment: Looks like jiangmiao/auto-pairs is the culprit: https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs/blob/f0019fc6423e7ce7bbd01d196a7e027077687fda/plugin/auto-pairs.vim#L469

Comment: I managed to reconcile it with auto-pairs. If anyone is interested, you can see my solution on https://github.com/MichaelWJung/dev-env/blob/650750f0370a30a320078cff70a54d09383271bd/.config/nvim/init.vim#L149

Answer (score 1):

```
set fo-=or
```

These options remove adding the comment leader automatically when pressing `o` or `O` in Normal mode, and when pressing  in Insert mode respectively.

see fo-table in vim help
`:h fo-table`

Comment: While legal, `set fo-=or` isn't really correct as it will not work unless `o` and `r` are adjacent in current configuration. You should run `-=` on one flag at a time.

Comment: Oh that's great to know! I always wondered why people list them out manually. I must have gotten away with it by luck