# Auto-insert C++ comment only on <shift+enter>

Tags: vimrc, comments, filetype-c++

The comment auto-insert feature is often very helpful and otherwise very annoying, depending on the kind of comment I am writing. Is it possible to bind the auto-insertion of `//` exclusively to `<shift+enter>`, and skip the auto-comment for ordinary `<enter>`? I thought about binding a key to some kind of temporary `setlocal`, but it seems too complicated since `setlocal` is meant for local scope (obviously) and not for immediate modifiers.

This earlier question is similar but really not the same: [Remove automatic comment leader](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15444/remove-automatic-comment-leader)

Comment: `inoremap <S-Enter> <C-\><C-O>:setl fo+=r<CR><CR><C-\><C-O>:setl fo-=r<CR>`

Comment: Thanks, well it works when I map it to `C-y` or any other control combo, but `<S-Enter>` seems not to be mappable. Any suggestion why not?

Comment: Your terminal doesn't [send distinct character code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/vim-how-to-map-shift-enter) when typing Enter vs Shift Enter. Vim can't distinguish keypresses that your terminal doesn't distinguish. You'd either have to configure your terminal to send a different escape sequence on Shift Enter, or use GVim (GUI Vim) which is preconfigured to handle this correctly.